# ZF2 Fatal error: Class 'Locale' not found in /home/...../Zend/I18n/Translator/Translator.php on line 228

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form, zend-locale

I have a project in my localhost, already running, after modifying the `php.ini`  of my `XAMPP` server [running on Windows 7] (adding: `extension=php-intl.dll`).
But when i upload this project to my `GoDaddy` hosting, it doesn´t works and get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Locale' not found in /home/content/41/9674641/html/library/zend.2.0.4/Zend/I18n/Translator/Translator.php on line 228
```

**GoDaddy hosting details:**

1. Php version 5.3
2. Operating system: Linux
3. i386-redhat-linux-gnu

**Zend Framework details:**

1. Zend Library: 2.0.4

I´ve tried what they say on the following links:

1. http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/1085/can-i-add-a-php-initialization-file-to-my-hosting-account?locale=en
2. http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/5647/why-isnt-my-phpini-file-taking-effect?locale=en&ci=46061

Also, i´ve called to 24/7 goDaddy support and they suggested me to create a php5.ini file in the root directory, then, they told me to  stop all web services (Cpanel/Stats & Monitors/System Processes/end web), but they didn´t told me what do i need to include in the php5.ini file.

I was reading some links and, as my localhost is a windows one, adding the extension=php-intl.dll to the php.ini file worked. So i´ve tried to include in my godaddy linux server: extension=php-intl.so but doesn´t works (neither extension=php-intl.dll).

The problem with the goDaddy hosting began when i started using ZF2 FORMs.

**Updates:**

1) I´ve got access to the php5.ini of the goDaddy server (i have made a copy on the root of my hosting) using **PUTTY**: `cp /web/conf/php5.ini /var/chroot/home/content/41/9674641/html`

Then i have read it and i could not find the **"intl" extension**, instead of this, i only could find:

```
; Windows Extensions
; Note that ODBC support is built in, so no dll is needed for it.
; Note that many DLL files are located in the extensions/ (PHP 4) ext/ (PHP 5)
; extension folders as well as the separate PECL DLL download (PHP 5).
; Be sure to appropriately set the extension_dir directive.

;extension=php_mbstring.dll
;extension=php_bz2.dll
;extension=php_curl.dll
;extension=php_dba.dll
;extension=php_dbase.dll
;extension=php_exif.dll
;extension=php_fdf.dll
;extension=php_filepro.dll
;extension=php_gd2.dll
;extension=php_gettext.dll
;extension=php_ifx.dll
;extension=php_imap.dll
;extension=php_interbase.dll
;extension=php_ldap.dll
;extension=php_mcrypt.dll
;extension=php_mhash.dll
;extension=php_mime_magic.dll
;extension=php_ming.dll
;extension=php_mssql.dll
;extension=php_msql.dll
;extension=php_mysql.dll
;extension=php_oci8.dll
;extension=php_openssl.dll
;extension=php_oracle.dll
;extension=php_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_shmop.dll
;extension=php_snmp.dll
;extension=php_sockets.dll
;extension=php_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_sybase_ct.dll
;extension=php_tidy.dll
;extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
;extension=php_xsl.dll
```

2) **goDaddy** response to my formal support request (ticket):

> Thank you for contacting Online Support
>
> I understand you are wanting to get Internationalization extension on
>   to your hosting account.  At this time these are not supported in our
>   systems at this time.  We are going to review this with our developers
>   to more information.  You may receive an email us down the road with
>   addition information about this.
>
> Please let us know if we can assist you in any other way.

Now i'm thinking that i have two problems:

A) Include the line to enable the extension (i don't know how):

Maybe could be:

```
extension_dir=/var/chroot/home/content/41/9674641/html/library/extensions/php-intl/usr/lib64/php/modules
extension="intl.so"
```

B) Include the extension in some location inside my hosting (but i don´t know how):

Maybe i could put the extension files inside: `/var/chroot/home/content/41/9674641/html/library/extensions/php-intl`

Also, i don't know where to acquire the extension files

C) Is there any known update on ZF2 (skeleton, library ..) that solve this issue ?

Please, i need help as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can manage PHP modules by using the "Change PHP version" feature of the cPanel interface. Select any version other than "native" and a list of checkboxes will appear.

http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/3937/viewing-or-changing-your-php-language-version?pc_split_value=2

Of course, their support might not immediately mention this solution, which should have been in their knowledge base in the first place.